# BULK INSERT across multiple related tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, bulkinsert

I need to do a BULK INSERT of several hundred-thousand records across 3 tables. A simple breakdown of the tables would be:

```
TableA
--------
TableAID (PK)
TableBID (FK)
TableCID (FK)
Other Columns

TableB
--------
TableBID (PK)
Other Columns

TableC
--------
TableCID (PK)
Other Columns
```

The problem with a bulk insert, of course, is that it only works with one table so FK's become a problem.

I've been looking around for ways to work around this, and from what I've gleaned from various sources, using a [SEQUENCE column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) might be the best bet. I just want to make sure I have correctly cobbled together the logic from the various threads and posts I've read on this.  Let me know if I have the right idea.

First, would modify the tables to look like this:

```
TableA
--------
TableAID (PK)
TableBSequence
TableCSequence
Other Columns

TableB
--------
TableBID (PK)
TableBSequence
Other Columns

TableC
--------
TableCID (PK)
TableCSequence
Other Columns
```

Then, from within the application code, I would make five calls to the database with the following logic:

- Request X Sequence numbers from TableC, where X is the known number of records to be inserted into TableC. (1st DB call.)
- Request Y Sequence numbers from TableB, where Y is the known number of records to be inserted into TableB (2nd DB call.)
- Modify the existing objects for A, B and C (which are models generated to mirror the tables) with the now known Sequence numbers.
- Bulk insert to TableA. (3rd DB call)
- Bulk insert to TableB. (4th DB call)
- Bulk insert to TableC. (5th DB call)

And then, of course, we would always join on the Sequence.

I have three questions:

1. Do I have the basic logic correct?
2. In Tables B and C, would I remove the clustered index from the PK and put in on the Sequence instead?
3. Once the Sequence numbers are requested from Tables B and C, are they then somehow locked between the request and the bulk insert?  I just need to make sure that between the request and the insert, some other process doesn't request and use the same numbers.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

After typing this up and posting it, I've been reading deeper into the [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) document. I think I misunderstood it at first.  SEQUENCE is not a column type.  For the actual column in the table, I would just use an INT (or maybe a BIGINT) depending on the number of records I expect to have).  The actual SEQUENCE object is an entirely separate entity whose job is to generate numeric values on request and keep track of which ones have already been generated. So, if I understand correctly, I would generate two SEQUENCE objects, one to be used in conjunction with Table B and one with Table C.

So that answers my third question.

Comment: Not entirely sure why you want to use sequences. What it sounds like you need are the auto generated PK's (AI's) from table C in order to do your inserts into table B, then the AI's from table B in order to do your inserts into table A. If you're trying to predict what the AI's will be for each table using a sequence, don't. There are better ways to predict the next AI. But, even those might be wrong if there are transactional failures, collisions, etc. Also, not 100% sure Bulk Insert is correct for your solution. Can you give more background on where the data you're inserting comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have the basic logic correct?

Yes.  The other common approach here is to bulk load your data into a staging table, and do something similar on the server-side.

From the client you can request ranges of sequence values using the [sp_sequence_get_range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sequence-get-range-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) stored procedure.

> In Tables B and C, would I remove the clustered index from the PK

No, as you later noted the sequence just supplies the PK values for you.

Comment: Ok ok... thank you. Yeah I just found the docs for `sp_sequence_get_range` right before you commented.  Can you do me a favor and walk me through how the process of using staging table(s) would work?  I mostly concerned with getting PK's and FK's to match up across the three tables.

Comment: It depends on what the source data looks like, and whether TableB and TableC have any unique columns.  If they do you can just load them, and then when you load TableA look up the PK based on matching the unique column.

Comment: The data in B and C is simple.  No unique columns. But I am still not getting the big picture here.  Tell me if I have this right.... I have 3 tables in the DB that mirror A, B, and C. Let's call them TempA, TempB and TempC.  From code, I do a raw dump of the three models into the Temp tables.  So now TempA, TempB, and TempC are full of data, but they are not related in any way. Do I have this right so far? Then... where do I go from here?

Comment: (this would be so much easier in a NoSQL table where I could just store JSON blobs!)

Comment: You can store JSON blobs in SQL Server if you want.  Really more of a data modeling decision.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017  Splitting out the tables gives you normalization (each piece of data is stored only once), and provides referential integrity.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, read your question wrong at first. I see now that you are trying to generate your own PK's rather then allow MS SQL to generate them for you. Scratch my above comment.

As David Browne mentioned, you might want to use a staging table to avoid the strain you'll put on your app's heap. Use tempdb and do the modifications directly on the table using a single transaction for each table. Then, copy the staging tables over to their target or use a MERGE if appending. If you are enforcing FK's, you can temporarily remove those constraints if you choose to insert in reverse order (C=>B=>A). You also may want to consider temporarily removing indexes if experiencing performance issues during the insert. Last, consider using SSIS instead of a custom app.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'm pretty sure I followed all of that.  But I also gotta say, this sounds a lot more complex (and possibly expensive) than the process I outlined in my OP.  No?  Help me understand what I'm not seeing.

Comment: It looks like David's walking you through the temp table portion. Main points: use tempdb to create the 3 staging tables (it's very similar to creating a normal table), bulk insert into those tables, then make the modifications on them by sending update statements in a single tran for each tbl. After your done, copy or MERGE these with the actual tables you want to have the data, then delete the tempdb tables. The other two points - temporarily removing constraints and disabling the indexes - apply to the target tables. The temp tables shouldn't be created w/ any of those to begin w/.

Comment: Ok, I can envision that entire process clearly in my head, but for one (very vital) part.. "then make the modifications on them".  What does that mean exactly?  I'm still unclear on how I get the PK's and FK's to match.

Comment: BTW, I REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: There are different ways to do it and it really depends on your data. But, the crux is that, for each table, you generate an update statement in code for every row. Then, you send all those update statements at once to the server in a single transaction.

Comment: Np. Look at this if you are unfamiliar with transactions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sorry for the string comments.. just saw your other questions regarding complexity and costs. You are right that this approach is more complex than your OP. But, it is much cheaper. People use this approach b/c it significantly reduces cost, which becomes substantial when you try to pull and process 100,000's of rows in memory.

Comment: Ok good to know! I think I will code both methods and then put a stopwatch around them to test. Right now, I can't see how the method you explained could possibly be cheaper than what amounts to nothing more than 3 bulk insert statements.  But, I'm going to try both.